# style trigger on listview subitem

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters

I have a `ListView` that is data-bound to color code the row of the item based on certain properties that come in. this is all working as intended.

I want to override a specific cell to change its color based on a different property.

the `ListView`....

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="dbItems" ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding connectionStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
            </Style>
            <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem.}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding badSubItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource cellConverter}}" />
            </Style>-->
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="DESCRIPTION" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding description}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="RESOURCE" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding resource}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="SubItem" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subItemFound}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Count" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding count}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

the initial color coding of each row is handled by a `Converter`.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{

        switch ((Interfaces.Enum.Status)value)
        {
            case Interfaces.Enum.Status.Unknown:
                return Brushes.LightGray;
            case Interfaces.Enum.Status.Offline:
                return Brushes.Red;
            case Interfaces.Enum.Status.Online:
                return Brushes.Green;
            case Interfaces.Enum.Status.OnlineButNotInitialized:
                return Brushes.OrangeRed;
            default:
                return Brushes.LightGray;
        }
}
```

the color change of the cell I was hoping to use another `Converter` for...

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(bool)value)
            return Brushes.LightGreen;
        return Brushes.Yellow;
    }
```

the problem is in the commented out style tag (second `ListViewItem` style) as this needs to apply only to a particular cell (subitem - bool) however I cannot seem to find the right binding type. can anyone assist me in this, or point me in the right direction to get this done...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `IsSomething` with the property you want to bind to

```
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridCell" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="{Binding IsSomething}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCell}" />
```